# How to parallelize my algorithm searching red pixel on bitmap

Tags: c#, .net, aforge

I find red pixel in bitmap, how to parallelize my algorithm that would search costs were less and to work more than one core on this algorithm.

Function `isRed` return red color in rgb.

```
        Bitmap tmpImage1 = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();

        int imageHeight = pictureBox1.Height;
        int imageWidth = pictureBox1.Width;

        for (int y = 0; y < imageHeight; y += 1)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < imageWidth; x += 1)
            {
                if (isRed(tmpImage1.GetPixel(x, y)))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Red pixel found", "RP", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: As a starting point, have a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537608(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Unless you have a serious problem with the amount of time it takes to find a pixel once, than I really wouldn't advise solving this problem with parallelism.  It will consume a lot more resources.

Comment: algorithm is constantly looking to find a pixel because it takes a lot of resources, not time

Comment: Well GetPixel is slow so you might want to look into using LockBits to get the BitmapData which is faster to work with, but more complicated.

Comment: my problem is that the program had worked on two cores or more and GetPixel  satisfied me.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only doing this once, than I would advise not using parallelism at all

The reason It won't work is because each sub task is fairly dependent on the other tasks.  Most of your threads will be searching an area that actually doesn't contain a red pixel, while one will be searching an area that does.

Not only that, but you'll have to merge the results of each thread when you're done, because only one of them will have found it.

---

But if you're searching for one red pixel on a lot of bitmaps, than that actually is a fine parallel problem.

If i needed to use parallelism, I'd probably use PLINQ:

Here's some documentation for that:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460714%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: the problem is that the algorithm calculates on a single core, im new i dont know how to do that(

Comment: @andrewbubblegum why is that a problem?

Comment: because one core is almost fully loaded

Comment: @andrewbubblegum are you actually observing a slowdown when you run the application?

Comment: yap, and image from stream freezes

Comment: the idea is that the algorithm would require fewer resources to search for pixel and want to do it 'cause i have a not fast cpu

Comment: @andrewbubblegum a paralell algorithm would actually use more resources.

Comment: @SamIam: It would complete faster too, so the net result would be the same.